apiClient.requestJWTUserToken of com.docusign.esign.client in Java 21
apiClient.requestJWTUserToken of com.docusign.esign.client
After upgrading Java 8 to Java 21 and Springboot version 3.2.5 got below error for apiClient.requestJWTUserToken
**Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/ws/rs/core/GenericType] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.ws.rs.core.GenericType
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526) ~[na:na]**
even after adding that particular dependency got error
added dependency for jakarta/ws/rs/core/GenericType

It looks like when you upgraded your library was upgraded but your reference is still calling for the older version. – you can see a similar issue here:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/core/Configuration
We hope this helps.
Adrian DocuSign Support

Docusign Java SDK supports using JWT authentication.
Here is the code to do that:
        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
        apiClient.setOAuthBasePath("account-d.docusign.com");
        ArrayList<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
        scopes.add("signature");
        scopes.add("impersonation");
        byte[] privateKeyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(prop.getProperty("rsaKeyFile")));
        OAuthToken oAuthToken = apiClient.requestJWTUserToken(
            prop.getProperty("clientId"),
            prop.getProperty("userId"),
            scopes,
            privateKeyBytes,
            3600);
        String accessToken = oAuthToken.getAccessToken();
        UserInfo userInfo = apiClient.getUserInfo(accessToken);
        String accountId = userInfo.getAccounts().get(0).getAccountId();

I highly recommend you download a quickstart ZIP file that not only have this code customized for your developer account, the tool will automatically create the configuration including the private RSA key needed for JWT auth as well as the correct userID for impersonation.
